# Optimality criterion for bimatrix game

Tags: game-theory

From point 1 to point 2 there are two paths such that path A is shorter than path B. Paths run 4 trains, which differ in the types of fuel consumed. The cost of travel along the chosen path is determined as the price of fuel multiplied by the length of the path. Each of the paths can handle only two trains at a time. Based on the total cost of the total travel, for each path are selected two trains that can travel along it. In accordance with this, for each path are determined strategy sets $A_1,B_1$="Select trains with the lowest total fare", $A_2,B_2$="Select trains with the highest total fare"  .

For these strategies, the payoff matrices of path (player) $A$ and path (player) $B$ were compiled by assigning a negative sign to the resulting values of the cost of travel along the two paths, depending on the strategy. The rows of the players' payoff matrices correspond to the strategies $(A_1,A_2)$, and the columns to the strategies $(B_1,B_2)$.

$A=\begin{pmatrix} -25650 & -8775 \\ -115275 & -98400 \end{pmatrix} B=\begin{pmatrix} -196800 & -230550 \\ -17550 & -51300 \end{pmatrix} $

Both players need to get the highest joint payoff (i.e. the lowest total cost of the route for all trains)

If we add up the winnings, then the greatest total winnings are provided by the strategy $(2, 1)=-115275+(-17550)=-115275$.

But from the definition of Nash equilibrium and Pareto optimality for bimatrix games, the best strategy is $(1,1)=-25650+(-196800)=-222450$.

If we solve a bimatrix game as a cooperative one, then the optimal Pareto optimal solution in the cooperative version, (we take $(0,0)$ as the utopia point - missed trains do not incur costs) when solving the problem [graphically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CVwS.png), is found in $(2,2)=−149700$. The Nash equilibrium solution will also be located at the same point. But the greatest overall gain is provided by the profitable strategy $(2,1)=−115275$

Is it correct to consider this game as a bimatrix game? How to formulate an optimality criterion to find the largest total payoff that corresponds to the strategy $(2,1)$?